# C++ Preprocessor concatenation operation

Tags: c++, concatenation, c-preprocessor

I would like to use the C++ preprocessor concatenator.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define GetBlack(colorName) (color.##colorName)

struct Color
{
    int black = 0;
};

int main()
{
  Color color;
  int c = color.black;
  int d = GetBlack(black); 
}
```

The error I get is

> 5:35: error: pasting "." and "black" does not give a valid preprocessing token
>   16:11: note: in expansion of macro 'GetBlack'

C++Shell:
http://cpp.sh/3547x

Any tips?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't actually want concatenation here. You are just pasting a preprocessing "token" into place, so just use:

```
#define GetBlack(colorName) (color.colorName)
```

The macro argument name `colorName` is expanded in place. Then

```
int d = GetBlack(black);
```

will expand into

```
int d = color.black;
```

Concatenation is for merging two "tokens" together into one, see [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html).

For instance, if the member was named `black_value`, but you just wanted to have to call `GetBlack(black)`, the macro definition would be something like:

```
#define GetBlack(colourName) colour.colourName##_value;
```